# Haskell: Non-exhaustive pattern in function

Tags: haskell

So i have a function, which takes a list of lists, and takes the head of each list and adds it to another list, I have guards which I thought covered all issues but it doesn't, can anyone see why it might be giving me an exception.

```
makeL :: (Eq a) => [[a]]->[a] -> [a]
makeL (h:t) l
    | length (concat (h:t)) == 0 = l
    | length h == 0 && length t /= 0 = makeL t l
    | length h /= 0 && length t == 0 = l++[head h]
    | otherwise = makeL t (l++[head h])
```

When I play about with it in prelude I can't replicate the error. but when I run the program if the `[[a]]` is equal to `[[],[],[],[],[]]` then it gives the error I think

Comment: Unrelated: this kind of "guard-based" anti-pattern seems to be quite popular lately on SO. Someone should write a "guards considered harmful" paper ...

Comment: This doesn't address your question at all, but I can't help but suggest it: you may like `concatMap (take 1)`.

Comment: I can't help mentioning that when you're tempted to use `length` on a list, you're usually making a mistake.

Comment: @chi, they're a lot better than nested `if/then/else`, but obviously not as good as pattern matching or eliminators when those will do.

Comment: @dfeuer I agree. I fear that many beginners still "think" in other languages, where testing whether a list is empty is done with an `if`, and translate that to guards. This neglects better alternatives for elimination, and leads to an error-prone and arguably unsafe constructor-test&partial-projection pattern, and to "boolean blindness". Worse, judging from the SO questions, the guard-based code is often wrong (!)

Answer (score 4):

`makeL (h:t) l` exclusively matches the case where the list of lists have a head and tail, but it doesn't match the empty list (which doesn't have a head).

As a bare minimum, you'll need to add a case that deals with the empty list:

```
makeL [] l = -- implementation goes here
```

Comment: In the program it can't get ' [] ' it will onlny have [[],[],[],[]]. But I have tried what you suggested and it still gives the error

Comment: "In the program it can't get ' [] ' it will onlny have [[],[],[],[]]." You might know that, but GHC doesn't, so it warns you about the non-exhaustive pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will pattern the job, but not using wards:

```
makeL :: (Eq a) => [[a]]->[a] -> [a]
makeL [] l              = l -- base case, empty list return l
makeL ([]:xs) l         = makeL xs l --case the list inside the list is empty, continue with the rest of the list
makeL ((x:xxs):xs)  l   = makeL xs l++[x] --if the list in the list have a head append to l and continue with the list
```